# Перенос на новую строку

Tags: php, html

Имеется такой вот код:

```html
<div class="grid__item grid__item--featured-collections small--one-half medium-up--one-fifth">
  <div class="grid-view-item">
    <a class="grid-view-item__link" href="/'.$row[" type_tovara "].'/'.$row["products_id "].'-'.ftranslite($row["title "]).'/">
      <div class="small--hide" style="margin-left: -35px;">'.$row["top_sales"].'</div>
      <div class="site-header__menu" style="margin-top: 22px; margin-left: -35px;">'.$row["top_sales"].'</div>
      <div class="small--hide" style="margin-left: -35px;">'.$row["under_order"].'</div>
      <div class="small--hide" style="margin-left: -35px;">'.$row["novelty"].'</div>
      <img class="grid-view-item__image" src="'.$img_path.'">
      <div class="h4 grid-view-item__title">'.$row["title"].'</div>
      <div class="grid-view-item__meta">
        <span class="visually-hidden">Regular price</span>
        <span class="product-price__price">'.group_numerals($row["price"]).' грн</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Отображается вот так, видно что слово "Новинка" налезла сверху на другую этикетку. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо чтобы последующие этикетки если есть то чтобы они были с новой строки, как не пытался сделать, не получается, всегда съезжают этикетки вместе с фоткой кофты...

Стили этикеток прикрепляю:

```css
.plus1{border:1px solid #0095EB;background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);color:#0095EB;
 z-index:3;border-radius:3px;padding:0px 4px 2px 4px;position:absolute;margin-left:35px;margin-top:-25px;font-size:12px;float:left;}
 
.plus2{border:1px solid #0095EB;background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);color:#0095EB;
 z-index:3;border-radius:3px;padding:0px 4px 2px 4px;position:absolute;margin-left:35px;margin-top:-25px;font-size:12px;float:left;}
 
.plus3{border:1px solid #0095EB;background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);color:#0095EB;
 z-index:3;border-radius:3px;padding:0px 4px 2px 4px;position:absolute;margin-left:35px;margin-top:-25px;font-size:12px;float:left;}
```

Пример как должно быть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, помогите мне!!!!!!!!

Comment: [mcve] надо было делать, чтобы помогли.

Answer (score 0):

Не вижу в коде чтобы использовались классы стилей добавленные ниже. У вас все стили используют абсолютное позиционирование, соответственно этикетки у вас группируются в одной точке. Попробуйте создать какой-нибудь контейнер для этикеток с абсолютным позиционированием. Вместо того, чтобы указывать его для каждой этикетки.

Вот пример с контейнером:

```html
<div class="grid__item grid__item--featured-collections small--one-half medium-up--one-fifth">
  <div class="grid-view-item">
    <a class="grid-view-item__link" href="/'.$row[" type_tovara "].'/'.$row["products_id "].'-'.ftranslite($row["title "]).'/">
      <div class="labels-wrapper">
        <div class="small--hide" style="margin-left: -35px;">'.$row["top_sales"].'</div>
        <div class="small--hide" style="margin-left: -35px;">'.$row["top_sales"].'</div>
      </div>
      ...
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

И затем добавить стиль

```css
.labels-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
}
```

А из классов .plus1, .plus2, .plus3 убрать position: absolute.

Comment: Не понимаю как создать контейнер... В коде не видно классы стилей потому что они берутся с базы.

Comment: @NoName поместить их в div - это и будет контейнер